# Converting AJAX REST call to a C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, rest

I have a AJAX call that works perfectly at **local server**. I'm trying to make the same call via C# (from another application/domain) but I'am very confused.

This is my webmethod:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public static object ParentLogin(string email, string password)
{
    List<object> ChildrenList = new List<object>();

    Usuario loggedUser = GetByEmailAndPass(email, password);
    if (loggedUser != null)
    {
        var children = Factory.Current.GetInstance<IChildrenBIZ>().GetAll().ToList();

        foreach (var item in children )
        {
            ChildrenList.Add(new { userid = item.Id, name = item.Nome });
        }
        return new { success = true, email = loggedUser.Login, users = ChildrenList};
    }

    return new { success = false };
}
```

This is my ajax call:

```
var url = "http://localhost/" + "LoginTest/Login.aspx/ParentLogin";
    var dataParams = "{ email: " + "'myemail@hotmail.com'" + ", password: " + "'123123'" + " }";

    ExecuteAjaxCall(url, dataParams, true, function (msg) {
        if (msg.d) {
            var success = msg.d.success; 
            var children = msg.d.users;

            if (children.length > 0) {
                $.each(children, function (i, item) {
                    if (item) {

                        var childID = item.userid;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }, StandardError);

});
```

Now I want to call this same Webthod via code behind. I tried usind Restsharper, but I couldn't make happen.
Anyone, please?

EDIT:

This is the ExecuteAjaxCall method:

```
function ExecuteAjaxCall(url, dataParam, isAssync, callBackSucess, callBackError) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: dataParam,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    assync: isAssync,
    success: function (msg) {
        callBackSucess(msg);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        callBackError(ERROR_MSG);
    }
});
}
```

IMPORTANT:

The main reason I want this is bacause I want to consume ParentLogin method from another domain. Maybe from a iOS or Android application! Is that the right approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a web site, or a web application project?

Comment: Can you post the code for ExecuteAjaxCall, or identify for us which JS library it's in, if you're using an off-the-shelf framework such as JQuery ?

Comment: John Saunders: It's a WebApplication.

Answer (score 3):

This web  method (a "Page Method", actually), is a public static method within your web application. You should be able to just call it:

```
namespace.Login.ParentLogin(email, password);
```

Comment: Thank you. I added more informations about my question. I need to be able to call this method from another domain/application/platform.

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor out a service class to hold your application logic so you can use it in another project instead of the RestSharp.

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public static object ParentLogin(string email, string password)
{
    return ServiceAdapter.ParentLogin(email, password);
}

public interface IService
{
    object ParentLogin(string email, string password);
}

public sealed class Service : IService
{
    public object ParentLogin(string email, string password)
    {
        List<object> ChildrenList = new List<object>();

        Usuario loggedUser = GetByEmailAndPass(email, password);
        if (loggedUser != null)
        {
            var children = Factory.Current.GetInstance<IChildrenBIZ>().GetAll().ToList();

            foreach (var item in children )
            {
                ChildrenList.Add(new { userid = item.Id, name = item.Nome });
            }
            return new { success = true, email = loggedUser.Login, users = ChildrenList};
        }

        return new { success = false };
    }

    //TODO move GetByEmailAndPass
}

public sealed class ServiceAdapter
{
    public static readonly IService Service = new Service();
}
```

Comment: If your project is simple then this is over-egging the cake a bit, but in general terms; I totally agree and this is my preferred method of approaching this problem. +1 for great minds thinking alike :)

Comment: Thank you! I added more informations about my question. I need to be able to call this method from another domain/application/platform.

Comment: You should look into using [`Xamarin`](http://xamarin.com/) if you want to use C# cross platform. If you want to use the native languages then you will need to make an API like what you were doing.